# Ruby sort array of arrays by subindex alphabetically

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have an array of arrays:

```
arr_of_arrs = [
  ["cart", "disk", "halt", "walk"],
  ["prot", "waco", "beau", "drab"],
  ["meet", "lick", "look", "itch"],
  ["find", "asks", "noun", "keen"],
  ["jive", "moon", "seem", "beam"]
]
```

How could I sort this array of arrays by the alphabetical order of the elements at specified index of the subarrays, say index 3, so its new order would be:

```
[
  ["jive", "moon", "seem", "beam"],
  ["prot", "waco", "beau", "drab"],
  ["meet", "lick", "look", "itch"],
  ["find", "asks", "noun", "keen"],
  ["cart", "disk", "halt", "walk"]
] #                        ^^^^^^ index 3 is ordered
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) is the method of choice here, but you could use [Array#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sort):  `arr.sort { |a,b| a[3] <=> b[3] }` if the sort index were `3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the index is `3`, then:

```
arr_of_arrs.sort_by{|a| a[3]}
```

Comment: not interested in following the ruby community style guides? https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide

Answer (score 5):

The questions asks how one can sort arrays by a single index. As others have shown how that can be done I've chosen to provide a generalized solution that addresses tie-breaking.

**Code**

```
def sort_by_index(arr, *idx_order)
  arr.sort_by { |a| a.values_at(*idx_order) }
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr = [["cart", "disk", "halt", "walk"],
       ["prot", "waco", "beau", "drab"],
       ["meet", "disk", "seem", "beam"],
       ["find", "asks", "noun", "keen"],
       ["jive", "disk", "look", "beam"]]
```

Note that `arr` differs from the array given in the OP's example.

*Sort by index 1*

```
sort_by_index(arr, 1)
  #=> [["find", "asks", "noun", "keen"],
  #    ["cart", "disk", "halt", "walk"],
  #    ["meet", "disk", "seem", "beam"],
  #    ["jive", "disk", "look", "beam"],
  #    ["prot", "waco", "beau", "drab"]]
```

*Sort by index 1, break ties with index 3*

```
sort_by_index(arr, 1, 3)
  #=> [["find", "asks", "noun", "keen"],
  #    ["meet", "disk", "seem", "beam"],
  #    ["jive", "disk", "look", "beam"],
  #    ["cart", "disk", "halt", "walk"],
  #    ["prot", "waco", "beau", "drab"]]
```

*Sort by index 1, break ties with index 3, break ties on first two indices with index 2*

```
sort_by_index(arr, 1, 3, 2)
  #=> [["find", "asks", "noun", "keen"],
  #    ["jive", "disk", "look", "beam"],
  #    ["meet", "disk", "seem", "beam"], 
  #    ["cart", "disk", "halt", "walk"],
  #    ["prot", "waco", "beau", "drab"]]
```

**Explanation**

Consider the second example, where `idx_order = [1, 3]`. Then, when sorting, elements `a` ("rows") of `arr` are compared by

```
a.values_at(*idx_order) #=> a.values_at(1, 3)
```

When comparing the first two elements of `arr` (`arr[0]` and `arr[1]`), the ordering of the following two arrays is determined:

```
["cart","disk","halt","walk"].values_at(1, 3) #=> ["disk", "walk"]
["prot","waco","beau","drab"].values_at(1, 3) #=> ["waco", "drab"]
```

The method [Array#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) is used to determine the order of these two 2-element arrays. (See, in particular, the third paragraph of the doc, which explains how arrays are compared "element-wise".)

Since

```
"disk" <=> "waco" #=> -1
```

`arr[0]` is found be precede `arr[1]` in the sort order.

Now suppose we compare `arr[0]` and `arr[2]`:

```
["cart","disk","halt","walk"].values_at(1, 3) #=> ["disk", "walk"]
["meet","disk","seem","beam"].values_at(1, 3) #=> ["disk", "beam"]
```

As both of these 2-element arrays have `"disk"` at index `0`, we must compare `"walk"` and `"beam"` to determine the tie-breaker:

```
["disk", "walk"] <=> ["disk", "beam"] #=> 1
```

which tells us that `arr[2]` precedes `arr[0]` in the sort ordering.

Comment: Thank you for the further explanation.

Answer (score 2):

To sort by the fourth element (i.e. index 3):

```
arr_of_arrs.sort_by { |a| a[3] }
```

or:

```
index = ->(i) { ->(a) { a[i] } }
arr_of_arrs.sort_by(&index[3])
```